# Всплывающее окно в зависимости от выбранной позиции в select

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет.

Представьте себе select (самый обычный). Хочу сделать всплывающее окно при нажатии на отр. позицию в select. Тут сразу непонятка, в первую очередь в том, что все всплывающие окошки JQ из инета рассчитаны только на 1 окно на одной странице. 2, 5, 10 - можно забыть.

Можно ли как-то при определенном выбранном value в select сделать всплывающее окно?

```
<select name="supername">
<option value="0">выбирите действие</option>
<option value="1">всплывающие окно с информацией 1</option>
<option value="2">всплывающие окно с информацией 2</option>
<option value="3">просто выбираем 3й пункт</option>
<option value="4">всплывающие окно с информацией 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JavaScript select</title>
</head>
<body>

<select name="supername" id="supername" onchange="foo()">
<option value="0">выбирите действие</option>
<option value="okno1">всплывающие окно с информацией 1</option>
<option value="okno2">всплывающие окно с информацией 2</option>
<option value="3">просто выбираем 3й пункт</option>
<option value="okno3">всплывающие окно с информацией 3</option>
</select>

<div id="okno1" style="display: none">
  <p>Okno1</p>
</div>

<div id="okno2" style="display: none">
  <p>Okno2</p>
</div>

<div id="okno3" style="display: none">
  <p>Okno3</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>

<script>
function foo() {

var newWin = open('/', 'example', 'width=600,height=400');
var selected = document.getElementById('supername');
content = document.getElementById(selected.value).innerHTML;

newWin.focus();
newWin.onload = function() {
var div = newWin.document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = content;
div.style.fontSize = '30px';

var body = newWin.document.body;
body.insertBefore(div, body.firstChild);
}; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Уважаемый. Сработало, супер! Даже конфликта с другими скриптами нет, но хотел не alert, а что то вроде div блока, в котором всего по нагружено. ( кстати alert у некоторых не работает, если скажем нажать галку - остановить выполнение сценариев для данной страницы )

кстати сработало при выборе пункта 3 ( я описал что этот пункт без окна, т.к. окошки не везде )

Comment: Можно <option value="DIVname"> и когда выбираешь из селекта значение, делать новое окно и загружать в него информацию из DIVname, имя можно окна так же можно сделать DIVname что бы была возможность открывать сразу несколько окон.

Comment: ох, я как раз спросил то, в чем разбираюсь плохо. с селектом я так понимаю:

    <select name="supername" id="supername" onchange="foo()">
    <option value="0">выбирите действие</option>
    <option value="okno1">всплывающие окно с информацией 1</option>
    <option value="okno2">всплывающие окно с информацией 2</option>
    <option value="3">просто выбираем 3й пункт</option>
    <option value="okno3">всплывающие окно с информацией 3</option>
    </select>

div'ы сами можно сделать display:none

а вот как скрипт к ним привязать, это бездна

Comment: можешь еще сделать проверку case'ом и если какие то value то не выполнять скрипт

Answer (score 1):

Если контент, в зависимости от выбранной позиции выпадающего списка, вы подгружаете динамически, то достаточно одного блока, в качестве модального окна. В противном случае, вам надо создать количество блоков равное элементам списка, с одним классом, который будет определять вид, позиционирование окна на странице. По выбору элемента списка, мы вычисляем его индекс и дальше, легким движением руки, открываем блок модального окна с идентичным индексом.

Comment: контент не динамический, блоки я уже создал. кол-во блоков расходиться с кол-вом элементов списка (я описал что скажем 3й элемент в списке - простой, без окна. хотя он может быть и не 3й). вид на странице - просто что бы div поместился, как обычно это бывает в многих примерах из инета ( мне не важно какой использовать ).

модальное окно - не вариант, т.к. можно его запретить. всплывающее окошко - совсем другое дело.

Comment: > модальное окно - не вариант, т.к. можно его запретить.

Не сможите запрететить. Тем более, что "*модальное окно*" === "*всплывающее окошко*".  В прочем, выше вам уже дали наводку на то, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: модальное окно, тот самый alert - можно поставить галку на нем, что бы не показывать его. при втором выборе из этого же select - ничего не произойдет (владельцы браузера опера меня поймут по любому). 

спросил, т.к. копал уже сам, и знаний в этой области не достаточно, что бы самому написать о чем спросил. На хэшкоде кстати есть темы связанные с всплывающими окнами, но только с одним

Comment: @frank, что бы вы запрещали в [этом случае](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/Pv764/)? И кстати, таких вспдывающих окон, как в примере, вы можете сделать сколько угодно.