# Несколько всплывающих окон на одной странице

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всех приветствую еще раз.

Можно ли на 1 странице сайта сделать несколько ссылок (`<a></a>`) , с разными всплывающими div'ами?

```
таблица, внутри обычные ссылки
ссылка 1 - всплывает окно 1, с информацией 1
ссылка 2 - всплывает окно 2, с информацией 2
...
ссылка 50 - всплывает окно 50, с информацией 50
```

Может ли кто привести пример полного кода?

p.s. это не менюшка с выпадающим списком пунктов, а окна, которые всплывают над всем, что есть на странице, по центру, в которых содержимое нужного мне кода (`<div></div>, <table></table>`)

[После неудачно заданного вопроса - решил более конкретно.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/161718/javascript-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-select)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.op_link a').click(function()
{
    $('#window_' + $(this).attr('name')).toggle();
});

<style>
.window { display: none; margin: 5% auto; width: 50%; height: 400px; position: fixed; left: 25%; border: 1px solid; }
</style>

<div id="window_1" class="window">window 1</div>
<div id="window_2" class="window">window 2</div>

<div class="op_link">
<a href="#" name="1">Open window 1</a>
<br />
<a href="#" name="2">Open window 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: супер!!1 а можно как то закрыть эту конструкцию? (ссылка на страницу - сбрасывает некоторые выбранные параметры на ней)